# array_flip, but not lose duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays

### EDIT: Apologies to the community. the question is flawed. if we try to have similar keys in an array, it can easily become problematic later on.

I wanna be able to use `array_flip` but don't want to lose duplicate keys.
So if I had an `array`

```
$arr = array( "red" => 1, "green" => 1, "orange" => 2);
```

Flipping this array `array_flip($arr)` will get me this:

```
array( 1 => "green", 2 => "orange" )
```

`red` is overwritten

Expecting after `array_flip`:

```
array(1 => "red", 1 => "green", 2=> "orange")
```

PS: if there's a duplicate that already exists I couldn't find, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: What if duplicate value is found to be used as a key while flipping? Do you just want a string array with values of initial array? Explain your wanted end result.

Comment: You will always have unique keys in an associative array. If you don't want to lose data, you will have to either have an array for each key or comma separated values.

Comment: what output you want ? say only possible array ?

Comment: what you want to do after flipping array ?